# find command in foreach doesn't work in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

Assume that command "find dir -name "script" is correct and printing all location of script in dir.
I want to do it with tcsh script

```
foreach f (find dir -name "script")
echo "$f"
$f #execute this script
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the backtick around your `find` command:

```
foreach f (`find dir -name script`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set locations = `find dir -name “script”`

echo “#\!/bin/tcsh” > scriptRunList

foreach location ( $locations )

    echo $location >> scriptRunList

end

chmod +x scriptRunList

scriptRunList
```

I think that does what you want and generates a list of the scripts that were run as a side effect.

tcsh $f - would work and no side effect files. I’m in the habit of keeping log files as I usually need to know what was run on which version at what time. Old habits.